# Django Tastypie Import Error on resources

Tags: django, tastypie

I have something strange going on that I can't seem to crack. I'm building an API with Tastypie and when I issue this call in my browser against localserver, it works fine: localserver/api/v1/userfavorite/?user__username=testowner

However, in my code, I'm getting an error: "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'". I realize it has to do with the user being treated as a request.user object, but I can't figure out where/why. I'm very confused why it works when issuing the API call in the browser, but in the code it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
# views.py
@login_required
def favorites(request):
    '''
    display a list of posts that a user has marked as favorite
    '''
    user = request.user
    favorites_url = settings.BASE_URL + "/api/v1/userfavorite/?user__username=" + user.username
    favorites = get_json(favorites_url)

    return render(request, "maincontent/favorites.html", {'favorites':favorites})

# resources.py
class UserFavoriteResource(ModelResource):
    '''
    manage post favorites by a user. Users can use a favorites list
    to easily view posts that they have liked or deemed important.
    '''
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    post = fields.ForeignKey('blog.api.resources.PostResource', 'post', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserFavorite.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'delete']
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'user':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

    def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
        # build the current user to save for the favorite instance
        bundle.data['user'] = bundle.request.user
        return bundle

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        # filter results to the current user
        return super(UserFavoriteResource, self).get_object_list(request)\
            .filter(user=request.user)

# utils.py
def get_json(url):
    # return the raw json from a request without any extraction
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    return data
```

Some notes:
 1. I have the post method working to create the UserFavorite item
 2. I can verify that the favorites_url is being generated correctly
3. I have tried hardcoding the favorites_url as well, same error.
EDIT: 4. I am logged in while doing this, and have verified that request.user returns the user

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because there is Anonymous user in your `request.user`. You are using `Authentication` it does not require user to be logged in. So if you perform requests call that request is not authenticated and `request.user` is AnonymousUser and that error occurs when you try to save Anonymous user to db. `Tastypie` documentation advices to not using browsers to testing things up, just curl instead. Browsers stores a lot of data and yours one probably remembered you have been logged to admin panel in localhost:8000 on another tab that's why it worked in browser.

I would prefer something like this:

```
def hydrate_user(self, bundle):
    """\
    Currently logged user is default.
    """
    if bundle.request.method in ['POST', 'PUT']:
        if not bundle.request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise ValidationError('Must be logged in')
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        bundle.data['user'] = \
            '/api/v1/userauth/user/{}'.format(bundle.request.user.pk)
    return bundle
```

Comment: I'm logged in while hitting the view, which has the @login_required decorator, as well as I have verified that request.user returns the user that I was logged in as. I will make some curl requests and see if I can find any more clues. Thanks.

Comment: so then, I don't understand what do you perform when you get that error?

Comment: So my answer is correct. get_json methods sends raw GET without session, cookies etc. Thats why user is anonymous in hydreate_user.

Comment: No, not quite. There's no problem on POST, it creates the object with the correct user. On GET is where I'm seeing the problem with nothing returning in the code. I've tried changing out hydrate user how you have it, just to check, and I'm getting the same behavior on GET.